# Reading map and ForwardRef error in Chart.JS - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am attempting to create charts with chart.js. I have followed the example code on the chart.js website and have been able to get the example code to work. I have tried amending the code to process the data for the chart externally from the javascript file creating the chart, then providing the data through the chart parameters. Doing this, I get the following console error:

[image]

I have the following data in my **data.js** file:

```
export const UserData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    year: 2018,
    users: 2000,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    year: 2019,
    users: 2500,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    year: 2020,
    users: 3000,
  }
]
```

I have the following code in my **App.js** file:

```
import React from "react";
import { UserData } from './Components/data';
import { Graph } from "./Components/graph";

const data = {
  labels: UserData.map((data) => data.year),
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Revenue',
    data: UserData.map((data) => data.users),
    backgroundColor: ['#CCD4BF'],
    borderColor: [],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

function App() {
  return <Graph graphData={data}/>
}
```

I have the following code in my **graph.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {Chart as ChartJS,} from 'chart.js/auto'

export function Graph(graphData) {

  return <Bar data={graphData}/>

}
```

Is there anything that I am missing in my code to resolve the "reading map" and "ForwardRef" errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, to solve this read about migration to react-chartjs-2@4 [here](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/migration-to-v4/#tree-shaking), that helped for me, I used the tree-shakable approach:

```js
import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { Chart as ChartJS, LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title } from 'chart.js';

ChartJS.register(LineController, LineElement, PointElement, LinearScale, Title);

<Chart type='line' data={chartData} />
```